# in C++, why compiler does not understand which object is pointed by base class object at compile time?

Tags: c++

in C++, why compiler does not understand which object is pointed by base class object at compile time?

For ex.

```
int Add(int nX, int nY)
{
    return nX + nY;
}
int Subtract(int nX, int nY)
{
    return nX - nY;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a function pointer and make it point to the Add function
    int (*pFcn)(int, int) = Add;
    cout << pFcn(5, 3) << endl; // add 5 + 3
    pFcn = Subtract;
    cout<< pFcn(5,3)<<endl // pefrom 5-3
    return 0;
}
```

Above code snippet is the example of Late binding or Dynamic binding.

In above example, at compile time only we came to know that 1st Add function is going to call through pFcn & then Subtract function is going to call. Then why it is called to be example of Dynamic binding even though compiler knows which function to call at compile time only?

---

my question is regarding to virtual function also. consider following ex,

```
class Base {
public:
    void NonVirtual() {
        cout << "Base NonVirtual called.\n";
    }
    virtual void Virtual() {
        cout << "Base Virtual called.\n";
    }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void NonVirtual() {
        cout << "Derived NonVirtual called.\n";
    }
    void Virtual() {
        cout << "Derived Virtual called.\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    Base* bBase = new Base();
    Base* bDerived = new Derived();

    bBase->NonVirtual();
    bBase->Virtual();
    bDerived->NonVirtual();
    bDerived->Virtual();
}
```

Here dynamic binding is happening. Which function to invoked is decided at run-time. So here why compiler can not decide at compile time only which function to invoke?

Comment: Fixing the title might make the question clearer - it currently has nothing to do with the actual question. "Object", "Base class" have specific meanings neither of which are relevant to this question as written.

Comment: In your second question, how are you determining that the decision is made at runtime?

Comment: thats what i wanted to understand. how decision is taken at run-time & why not at compile-time? I have taken this example from another site where it is mentioned that dynamic binding is happening but it is not mentioned why & how.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, using function pointers *requests* late binding, but a sufficiently smart compiler could optimize that request and early-bind instead if it can prove that only one function could ever be bound.  This is permitted by the [as-if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) optimization rule:

- Late binding was requested by the program.
- But *early binding does not change the observable behavior of the program.*  Early binding is desirable because it is faster, makes the program smaller, and requires less RAM (`pFcn` can be removed).
- Therefore, early binding may be performed instead.

Consider instead where you might pass function pointers around in a way where the compiler is unable to early-bind, either because it is not smart enough to detect that it is possible, or because it is interacting with code that it cannot observe:

```
using BinaryIntegerOperator = int (*)(int, int);

int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int Subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

extern int accumulate(
    int initial,
    int *first,
    std::size_t count,
    BinaryIntegerOperator op
);
```

Now you can pass `Add` or `Subtract` as the fourth argument.  The called function may not be part of the same binary (perhaps it's part of a dynamically-linked library) and so late binding is inevitable -- `accumulate()` would have already been compiled by a different compiler.

Comment: In dynamic binding, vTable is instantiated at run-time & not at compile time, thats why compiler does not understand which function to call at compile time for the virtual functions. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Neeta Your question has nothing to do with virtual functions. The contents of a vtable can generally be determined entirely at compile time. Calls to virtual functions can still be dispatched statically if the compiler can prove that there is only one function that could possibly be called (for example, if the call was not made through a reference/pointer, or if the member being invoked is `final`, or if the type being invoked on is `final`).

Comment: @Neeta If your question is about virtual functions then please edit it. The content of your question does not even mention virtual functions at all.

Comment: I have edited my question & added one more question regarding virtual function, please have a look at it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where the compilation system can prove there is exactly one function that can be called, it is allowed, but not required, to remove the indirect call and to call the function directly. This applies for both function pointers and virtual method dispatch. Generally for virtual methods, the optimization would happen as part of link time optimization where the linker realizes there is only one instance of a given class with a virtual method, or perhaps no classes which ever override a virtual method.

I'm not sure either optimization is considered incredibly important, but I expect both do happen in simple circumstances with the best compilers. (The first example will fall out of fairly standard compiler optimization techniques. Doing it for vtables will almost certainly require a purpose built optimization pass as the compiler has to know how the vtable is and is not modified at runtime.)

Generally that a use of a mechanism simplifies away does not mean one is not using the named mechanism. That is why one might say the function pointer is dynamic binding even though the compiler can prove it does not have interesting dynamic behavior.

Given the updated code above, consider the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Base* bBase = new Base();
    Base* bDerived = new Derived();

    // Use test on argc to abstract arbitrary computation.
    Base *one_or_the_other = (argc > 1) ? bDerived : bBase;
    one_or_the_other->NonVirtual();
    one_or_the_other->Virtual();
}
```

The compiler can no longer determine at compile time which virtual method to call for the second dispatch.